# Installing dependencies for a Bit component that uses an env

Tags: reactjs, bit.dev

I'm using several react components that uses a custom react env. Out of these for one of these components, I need to install a dependency package.

Do I need to install it at Env where it will be available for all the components or can we install it directly to the particular component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would only set the dependency via the env if, like you said, you wanted it to be applied to all components using that env.

To set a dependency for a single component (or group of components, via string glob pattern) use the `bit deps set` command
https://bit.dev/reference/reference/cli-reference/#deps-set

Comment: Let's say if its the same dependency and different versions, which one get the precedence? Is it `bit deps set` or the one inherited from Env?

Comment: bit deps set.- is the convention for this as `npm package name` ?